# malformed syntax from phone browser

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an angular API on the front end which calls the backend C# both hosted on Azure,

The site can be viewd on PC browser, but when I try to navigate to the site from my phone, I get a "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax." from Azure's stream

I am using

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

to call the back end

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when i was trying to browse the website on the phone it did it using "http://" but once i changed it to "https://" it started working